# Updating app in the app store and more

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, app-store

I am about to finish my first application and have got everything working. However, i am wondering the following and would really appreciate some advice and help.

My app have a Core Data sqlite3, it is a quiz app, with the questions data and a .plist with the players score.

1. When i need to update the question DB or the app, in the app store, how do i preserve the player score .plist?
2. I am generating the core data sqlite3 data from .txt files in the simulator and then remove that module. How do i go about to only update the DB in the application without a code update?
3. Can someone give me some advice how you handle version numbers in general? What would you do in regards to this if you only update the DB with added questions?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files that are inside this directory

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

do not get removed when your app is updated. This is the answer to your first question.

I'd say that good manners would be to update your DB from some web page automatically. You should store the version number of your local DB file and compare it to the one on the remote server. Whenever the local DB is outdated, ask the user if he/she wants to get a new version.

Comment: so that means that the update of the DB is not done via the appstore?

Comment: You can't update only one resource file of your application in App Store. You should always provide a full update. Maybe I misunderstood your comment. Yes, I am suggesting updating resource files over the network.